# Get variable from mySQLi to PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm pretty new to the whole PHP and mySQLi thing... But at the moment I am trying to make a simple project where I would like to read a **specific** value from a mySQL database, and then simply print (echo) it..

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     if($username == '' || $password == ''){
          echo 'please fill all values';
     }else{
          require_once('dbConnect.php');
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
          $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
          if(isset($check)){
               echo 'All values match!';
          }else{ 
               echo 'These values do not match!';
          }
      mysqli_close($con);
     }
}else{
     echo 'error';
}
?>
```

I don't know if it is that obvious... but this is actually code for an app. But I mainly want to know how to get a specific value from mySQL as a PHP variable?

I will be using the username to search for the correct variables

Let's say the table looks like this :

```
username        password        money

  guy             123            10
```

then I want to use 'guy' to find the amount of money and print it to the screen.

Sorry if this is asked and/or explained badly...

Comment: `echo $check['money'];` ?

Comment: Hash your user's passwords. Use parameterized queries. This code is dangerous as is. You also should execute the query and fetch separately, if one fails you wont know which with the current approach.

Comment: loop over successful results and echo the column(s)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be much communication going on anywhere in there, be it comments/answers, eh @RajdeepPaul ? ;-)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: @tadman ... First of all, I'm not just looking for "quick answers"... Second, as I said I'm very new to this so you don't have to be rude about how bad the code is...

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Well, the OP posted comments in answers and they're not getting responses; lovely "after sales services" eh?

Comment: @Fred-ii- What do you mean by that? I'm trying to figure out how to use the actual code...

Comment: @JohanDewaal what I meant by that Johan was, that the people to whom you posted comments under their answers aren't being very communicative with you and you deserve a reply to those. I'm also wondering if any of those have solved the question you asked and if not, what problem are you facing right now?

Comment: @JohanDewaal It can be difficult to deal with new programmers when all they want to do is bulldoze ahead without taking any of the warnings people given them into consideration. You have a number of serious problems with your approach here, that's why I've added those flags. Any time I see "money" and SQL injections in the same code I become immediately concerned. You **must** approach this in a disciplined way or you put your users at risk, if not your company or career. Please, don't use this code in any form, it needs a fundamental rewrite. Sorry to be harsh, but hackers are much harsher.

Comment: @tadman ... Look I'm not completely a "new programmer"... But the 'money' was just an example (i quote) "Let's say the table looks like this :" but either way, I know this is not even close to the real thing here.... But I guess I have to start somewhere just to get an idea of what I'm doing?

Comment: @JohanDewaal Please pay attention to what Fred-ii and tadman are saying here. All of us are trying to help you out here. You've been given two answers below. What issues are you facing now?

Comment: @JohanDewaal Even with that issue aside you still have a huge number of problems here, plain-text passwords, SQL injection holes, no method or structure to development. If you're looking to produce applications, not just quick tests, please, find a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that fits your style and meets your needs. Writing code this way is extremely painful, there's so many things you have to do manually or you'll have your site exposed to innumerable risks. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is very beginner friendly and worth exploring.

Answer (score -2):

change the code like this where you are making query

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$money= $row['money'];
}
```

//So because your query will return only one user if the ///username is unique so //now you can print money anywhere.

Comment: Wait.. sorry I am very new to this, so is $money the variable that will now match the username?

Comment: This doesn't do much. It simply assigns a variable to the fetched row.

Comment: @JohanDewaal I guess I'm the one that gets to respond on their part. The answer Johan is yes. However, this answer failed to include the echo for `$money= $row['money']`.

Comment: Thanks! So I will have to add "echo $money"? Or am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry I forgot to put in your username

Comment: @JohanDewaal Yes. However, I don't feel it's right for me/us to be doing all the work for these people who have posted answers and not respond or have just left. They get the credit and we do the work. Put that example in a real world situation ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's okay, I now have an idea of what to do (with the framework and stuff...)... Thanks for all your help! But yeah you don't have to waste your time or anything ;)...

Comment: @JohanDewaal you're welcome. I didn't waste my time per se, I just don't appreciate someone else taking the credit for everyone else's work. Rajdeep originally gave you [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654968/get-variable-from-mysql-to-php/41655023?noredirect=1#comment70508550_41654968) being `echo $check['money'];` which would have solved this right away. All these guys probably did was base themselves on that and pasted it in. I also mentioned to loop over results and echo the column(s), yet I take it that you haven't worked in databases for long, so I can respect that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks a lot ! And yeah I'm pretty new to this stuff... But I'm going to learn more about this stuff! XD... Thanks again! Have a nice day/night (whichever works for you)